# Understanding Kullback-Leibler divergence as random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, P)$ a probablity space and $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}_1)$ a measurable space be given.

According to Watanabe's textbook, the following text

> the kullback-Leibler divergence(or so-called relative entropy),
> $K(q\parallel p^*)$ is a **measurable function** of the random samples
> $D_n=\left \{ X_1,....X_n \right \} $

is described. (On the textbook, $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable which is subjected to a probability function $q(x)dx$ and random variable $X_i $ are independently subject to the same probability distribution of $X$. Of course, $q$ is a true function and $p^*$ is estimated function from the sample $D_n$. In Other words, if we choose a sample $D_n$, we can get the corresponding estimate function
$q^*$, or shortly expressing, $D_n \mapsto p^*$)

I want to check why Kullback-Leibler divergence is actually a measurable function. Since Kullback-Leibler distance maps to estimated value $q^*(x) \in D_n  \subset \Omega \overset{X(q^*)} \mapsto  \int _{A} q(x)log\frac{p(x)}{q^*(x)} \in \mathbb{R}$ . For convenience, $X(\cdot):=K(p\parallel \cdot ) $. Then the claim is

**Claim** : $X^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{B}$, for all $A \in \mathcal{B}_1$.

By verifying the claim, we can define a measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B}_1)$ by defining the definition $\mu(A)= P(X^{-1}(A)) = \int_{A} \mu dx = \int_{A} q(x)log\frac{p(x)}{q^*(x)}=K(p \parallel q^*)$

Here is my guess, (and I yet not have proven the **Claim** that I constructed) but it seems to be really awkward because I forcibly try to apply the definition of the measurable function to the given situation. and that's the optimal way that I think. is it a right way to check that Kullback-Leibeler divergence measurable function? If not, how to verify Kullback-Leibler distance is measurable function by the definition of measurable function?